# rosbag not publishing clock

Tags: ros, bagfile, clock

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I recorded some bagfiles with different experiments, then using the rosbag cookbook I change some timestamps (http://www.ros.org/wiki/rosbag/Cookbook).
Now when playing back the new bagfiles, the clock is not being publish.
I've already set the use_sim_time parameter to true and playing the bagfile with --clock option. What could be wrong?

EDIT: I re-run my program and remove the compression options for the bag file. When writing uncompressed bagfiles, the clock works with no problems.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/63410/rosbag-not-publishing-clock/) by [Javier](https://answers.ros.org/users/277/javier/) on ROS Answers with karma: 408 on 2013-05-24

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [demmeln](https://answers.ros.org/users/1370/demmeln/) on 2014-06-02**:
Could you provide a downloadable bag file with this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This seems to be a bug (https://github.com/ros/ros_comm/issues/82) in rosrun.

(Too low karma to post a link. Will edit when possible)

---

Originally posted by [lucasb.eyer.be](https://answers.ros.org/users/14676/lucasb.eyer.be/) with karma: 61 on 2014-04-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2